# how i can fix my captcha error for register page in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

```
     controller
```

---

```
    > register validation and captcha

    public function register_process()    {




    if($this -> form_validation -> run()){
     $fname = $this -> input -> post('txt_fname');
     $lname = $this -> input -> post('txt_lname');
     $email = $this -> input -> post('txt_email');
     $pass = $this -> input -> post('txt_pass');
     $captcha = $this -> input -> post('txt_captcha');
```

---

**is this wrong**
 //is there anything wrong?
            $this -> captcha_check();
            }
            else
           $this -> show_register();

---

### after that

```
    public function captcha_check(){
        $word = $this -> session ->userdata('cap_word');
```

//if captcha right  send mail else  dont send
                if($word==$captcha){
                  $key = md5(uniqid());
                   $this -> load -> library('email');
                   $this -> email -> initialize();

```
               $this -> email -> from('simi.php@gmail.com','مدیر سایت');
               $this -> email -> to($email);
               $this -> email -> subject('تاییدیه ایمیل');

            $message  = 'از ثبت نام شما ممنونیم<hr/>';


    //in model it add people in temp table
            if($this -> email -> send()){
                $this -> model -> add_temp_user($email,$pass,$key);
                //redirect('main/semi_success');
            $this -> semi_success();
            }
   //here show errors
            else {
                echo $this -> email -> print_debugger();
            }               
        }
        else{
        $this -> show_register();
        }

    [![enter image description here][1]][1]


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmHWy.png
```

Comment: Could you share your full code. it is not clear whats going on

Comment: Need more code to help.